# How to speed up the page with lots of table cells?

Tags: php, html, css

In my project I have one table with 24*6*300 cells on one page (it's script for rendering the statistics) - 24 columns for hours * 6 columns for 10minutes * 300 rows. Every cell has tipsy popup with additional information. The problem is, it's very very slow. Not only the rendering but the overal work with the page too. What do you recommend if I want to speed it up ?
(substituting cells with divs? with ul? rendering the table as image and to use imagemap for hover effect?)

Comment: How are you rending it? in a loop

Comment: Yes. But the rendering is not the biggest issue. After the rendering is done, the browser reacts very slowly ..

Comment: how are the popups realized? my guess is, that not the tablecells as such, but bound javaScript for each cell is the problem

Comment: The popup handlers are not the problem. I disabled it, it is a bit faster but still very slow.

Comment: It will be slow, simply because you have created at least 43501 objects (including `<table>` and `<tr>`) on a single page, and it's eating the client computer's memory. You are then using Javascript to create hover effects, which you say displays "additional information" which also has to be loaded into memory, which uses yet more memory. The *only* way to speed it up is to reduce the number of objects on the page. Having that number of objects in the DOM will take a long time to search through whenever JS tries to reference one (e.g. with `getElementById()`).

Comment: I would paginate the number of rows per page, a table with 300 rows of  144 cells each won't be very readable anyway.

Comment: Every cell has only the background-color set. Ok I know it's bit silly approach how to do this thing, but I thought there were some elements (div?ul?) which are eating less memory than td..

Comment: An element is an element is an element at the end of the day. If you use something other than a table, you will have to create a load of complicated CSS (probably with a whole bunch of browser specific hacks) in order to get it to display correctly, and what you gain on the swings you will lose on the roundabouts, as it were. You would still have as near as makes no difference the same number of elements on the DOM, and this will make JS selector methods very slow. The "render as image" idea might help, but it would make load time slow and increase server load heavily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my advice:

**1. Paginate and/or remove clutter**

Maybe you could display only one hour of data per page? Maybe you could simplify and display only basic information on the screen and provide a more comprehensive result when user specifically requests it?

**2. Remove CSS3 styling**

Text shadows, transformations, etc. take a lot of CPU. Remove them if they have an important impact on performance. In my opinion a better page is the one that's fast and ugly than the one that's beautiful and extremely slllllooooooowwwww...

**3. JavaScript on page??**

Pinpoint leaks, optimize, refactor.

Hmmm... anything else?

Comment: `In my opinion a better page is the one that's fast and ugly than the one that's beautiful and extremely slllllooooooowwwww...`: +1 that!

Answer (score 2):

I am expecting you are not showing 43200 objects in the browser visible area consider adding rows on user scroll event and removing which are currently not in the visible area.

Comment: Not a bad idea, as long as you remove the ones that have disappeared as well. Potentially very complicated to write but it could work...

Answer (score 0):

You can render huge data tables in a fancy way using [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are concerned about particular DOM elements being more memory/processor intensive. It may be true in your case that you may end up with an extra element or two by using tables instead of div's. But to end up with the same thing functionally and visually you would just end up getting into a mess that quickly becomes unmaintainable. You would need a whole mess of CSS and maybe some JavaScripting to get it work. Not to mention that semantically it would be meaningless. Tables are for tabular data, like what you have.

Now you could go crazy and try to code from scratch or you could use one of the many tools out there to get the job done. I suggest leveraging other people's hard work and using a freely available tool. Consider using [Data Tables](http://datatables.net/). You will likely need some kind of pagination or 'infinite scrolling'/lazy loading solution. Data Tables comes with an extra called 'scroller' that can handle the infinite scrolling for you.

Good luck.